# Passing multiple rows as a single batch for prediction using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a standard sklearn ml model (random forest). However, my data is a collection of rows, each having a column of `date` and `time`

**Example data:**

```
category company date time
---------------------------
0        a       1    0700  
0        b       2    0500   
1        c       3    0400 
1        c       3    0300   
0        c       1    0800    
..
```

The categorization here is binary i.e. `0` or `1`. Here, the dataset is processed such that all rows with the same `date` are categorized as `1` or `0`

**Sorted Data:**

```
category company date time
---------------------------
0        a       1    0700
0        c       1    0800    
---------------------------
0        b       2    0500  
--------------------------- 
1        c       3    0400 
1        c       3    0300   
..
```

Here the delineation is made with respect to the `date` column. There is no fixed number of rows per date batch.

While I can pass to the sklearn model each individual row with their classification, I am unsure how can i pass sklearn a batch to *predict* i.e. a number of rows with the same date to be classified.

**Unknown Data of Same Date (categorization to be predicted):**

```
category company date time
---------------------------
?        a       5    0700
?        c       5    0800    
?        d       5    0400 
?        d       5    0300   
..
```

One suggested method was to 'transpose' my dataset such that every batch fits into a *single* row with multiple columns each corresponding to an entry in the `date` set. However this seems to be too time consuming as every column would have a unique header i.e. `company_0`, `company_1`... `company_n`.

How do I pass sklearn a batched dataset of a single date (csv) so that it can categorize all entries in that batch where every row in a single date has the same categorization, `1` or `0`?

Comment: What is time consuming, is it transposing the data or when you fit the model ? Because this seems like the only way to solve your problem

Comment: Transposing the data i.e. to 30 rows (for each day) with N columns for each cell (e.g. company_a, company_b .. time_0700, time_0800). I don't think it is impossible to transpose, just that I'm new to ML so I was wondering if there's a way to solve this by 'batching' or something akin to an 'object' which encapsulate all rows in a date, or can i only strictly pass in a single row for prediction?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but you can ask your question on the [cross_validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) forum which is the stats/machine learning stack forum. You will have more chance to get an accurate answer there